# Drawing a single pixel using DMA2D

Tags: stm32, c

I'm trying to draw a single pixel using DMA2D.
I did the following code it's not working at all.
LCD Display Width is 320, Height is 240.

I assumed a 1x1 pixel rect as a pixel.

```
  DMA2D_HandleTypeDef hdma2d;
  hdma2d.Instance = DMA2D;
  hdma2d.Init.Mode = DMA2D_R2M;
  hdma2d.Init.ColorMode = DMA2D_OUTPUT_RGB565;
  hdma2d.Init.OutputOffset = 320-1;


  if (PIXELWINDOW.pos.x <= PIXELWINDOW.end.x &&

      PIXELWINDOW.pos.y <= PIXELWINDOW.end.y) {
      HAL_DMA2D_Init(&hdma2d);
      HAL_DMA2D_Start(&hdma2d, c, (uint16_t)OLED_BUFFER[0] + (PIXELWINDOW.pos.x + PIXELWINDOW.pos.y*320)*2, 1, 1);
      HAL_DMA2D_PollForTransfer(&hdma2d, 10);                    
  }
```

Comment: (uint16_t)OLED_BUFFER[0] + (PIXELWINDOW.pos.x + PIXELWINDOW.pos.y*320)*2 this is definitely wrong :). T

Comment: @P__J__ Can you tell me the fix and post an answer with explanation ? Please Thanks so much for your feedback

Comment: You don pass the address of the start of the buffer only   value of the first element `(uint16_t)OLED_BUFFER[0]` =>  `&OLED_BUFFER[0]`